# Ввод строки C++

Tags: c++

Как ввести строку неизвестного размера без использования `cin` и `string` и узнать ее размер?

Comment: Читать посимвольно и выделять достаточное количество памяти?

Comment: "Как написать программу на C++ не используя C++?" - оригинально, чо.

Comment: @gbg и ответом в итоге зачтен вариант с известным максимумом, хотя задача была про 'строку неизвестного размера' ))

Comment: @kroder - улыбаемся и машем, чо. Ладно, что там максимум фиксирован, там еще и баг сидит - будет весело, когда этот максимум кто-нибудь превысит.

Comment: Плюс @gbg, ибо "писать" на плюсах и использовать лишь то, что пришло с C - просто глупо. Или не глупо ?) Чтобы это понять, хотелось бы узнать у Юрия, по какой причине он отказался от cin и std::string ?)

Comment: @oleg.vorobiov scanf работает быстрее, и почему-то в некоторых тестирующих системах ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); не работает

Comment: @gbg, это то, что хотелось узнать, ограничения на строку были известны

Comment: @Юрий, можно конкретный пример, когда ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0) у Вас не работает ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только придумать заведомо максимальную длину. Как-то так, например:

```
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 255 // или сколько хотите

...

char buf[MAX_STRING_LENGTH ];
scanf("%s", buf);
int length = strlen(buf);//здесь будет длина
```

Comment: Категорически недопустимо полагать, что существует какая-то "заведомо известная максимальная длина". 90% взломов начинались с того, что программист взломанного софта при разработке говорил эту фразу...

Comment: А как Вы предлагаете? Не помню точно, как работает функция scanf_s, но там решена проблема с переполнением, можно использовать ее.

Comment: `scanf_s` не входит в стандарт. Она, можно считать, Microsoft-specific.

Comment: @АлексейСаровский C чтением посимвольно, обработкой по выходу за пределы отведенного буфера, выделением дополнительной памяти и проверкой двух условий - считывания `\n` или `EOF`.

Answer (score 5):

В данном случае, наиболее правильным и логичным будет как раз использование `cin` и `std::string`.

**Обоснование следующее:**

- Данный код будет предельно кратким
- он использует стандартную библиотеку, а значит, не требует дополнительных включений
- любой программист на C++ сразу поймет, о чем идет речь

**Дополнительный слабый аргумент**

- Сам Страуструп настоятельно рекомендует по максимуму использовать встроенные средства языка, а не писать на C++ как на C.

Единственный аргумент "за" написание велосипеда - это оголтелый креатифф, либо чокнутый преподаватель (еще хуже, интервьюэр-болван на собеседовании), который не может адекватно поставить задачу.

В адекватной постановке, эта задача ставилась бы так:
"cin>>string работает слишком медленно (приводится тест), обгоните его!"

Тогда бы появлялась цель обогнать стандартную библиотеку. А пока такой цели нет - и задачи нет.